# python if condition to show the difference between two numbers by 1

Tags: python-3.x

Can anyone tell me how to use if statement in python for the difference between the two nos is 1..??
I have written like below and I am getting error

if num1 = num2 + 1:

what should be the content with if?

Answer (score 0):

You use `=` for assigning a value to a variable; you use `==` for comparing the quality of two values.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the correct syntax in the [Python 3 Control Flow Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements).

Checking the difference between two integers can be achieved as follows:

```
if x - y == 1:
    print("Difference between x and y is 1.")
```